# 32 or 64 bit on 4GB ram acer netbook

Tags: acer, ram, architecture

I have a netbook with 4Gb RAM
Should I choose 32 or 64 bit?
What is the speed difference?
How is the compatibility  with 32bit applications?

Comment: What's the machine? Not all CPUs can support 64bit and that would make the decision a lot more simple for you.

Comment: could you please mention which laptop you are using or cpu??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own comment: Given they're shipping 4GB of RAM in this, it's almost certainly already running a 64bit operating system which suggests its CPU is almost certainly capable of running a 64bit operating system.

I'd go for 64bit.

There is the occasional complication but that's usually all it is, a complication. They're usually all solved by installing `ia32-libs`. The biggest problem I think I've *ever* had (in half a decade of running 64bit) was getting Adobe Air to run and even that didn't keep me down for long (that's what Ask Ubuntu is for!). Some people hit weird edge cases with some drivers but we're talking *really* rare stuff.

As for a benchmark between the two... I can't give you that. It's really going to vary between CPUs, as these things do. There is a speed improvement though. [Phoronix did some testing on 13.04](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_x86_1304&num=1). Use that illustratively.

Comment: Yeah [its CPU supports 64 bit](http://ark.intel.com/products/59802/). You should be fine.